# react component library image is not showing when publish package

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, webpack, npm-publish

I use [create-react-library cli](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library) and create component.

my component import image as follow :

```
import avatarImage from "../assets/avatar.png";

<img src={avatarImage} />
```

and when publish it to github npm pkg , and install it in project , the "*node_modules>component>dist*" folder has image file with name "avatar~bmRXRbfb.png".

but nothing showing in my react app ,and also "inspect" page has  tag like this :

```
<img src="avatar~bmRXRbfb.png" >
```

it seems webpack work fine and bundle image correctly but address to image is not working .

**update :**

when import that image from component dist folder , it show image :

```
import image from '@component/dist/avatar~bmRXRbfb.png"

<img src={image} />
```

this way image path changes to media folder.

**update 2:**

when manually copy "avatar~bmRXRbfb.png" to public folder everything work fine !!!